# Non-functioning keyboard in Linux

Tags: system-installation, keyboard

So I recently decided to start using Linux. While trying Linux Mint from a USB, no key on the keyboard of my Surface (240gb ssd, 8gb RAM, i5 8th gen) laptop was working. I then tried Ubuntu and encountered the same issue.

My touchpad works and the onscreen keyboard also works. I thought that maybe I am missing updates or something, and after some online searching I found some command line instructions to make it work.

So I connected to WiFi and installed the drivers from Xorg, but in order for them to run, I need to restart. However, since I am using a USB stick, nothing is saved after restarting. Also, I cannot install Linux on my laptop because it requires you to write a password, with a physical keyboard. The onscreen keyboard disappears when you click in the password field. It's not a keyboard setting issue like "key debounce" or something like that.

How can I resolve this? Would an external keyboard work? I have read that in some cases it does but in others it doesn't.

Comment: What computer is it? Do you have a USB keyboard you could use temporarily?

Comment: @vidarlo microsoft surface laptop model 1769, no I don't have a USB keyboard.